# Loading GeoJSON into Meteor's leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, leaflet, geojson

I am quite new to Meteor. I am trying to implement my own custom version of this example from leaflet into Meteor: [Interactive Choropleth Map](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html)

It uses this file to import GeoJson Data: [us-states](http://leafletjs.com/examples/us-states.js)

**My problem is**: importing this file or getting it to render.

**What I have done:**

```js
Template.map.rendered = function() {

  var map = L.map('map').setView([37.8, -96], 5);

  L.tileLayer.provider('Stamen.Watercolor').addTo(map);
  
  HTTP.get(Meteor.absoluteUrl("/us-states.js"), function(err,result) {
    var statesData = result.content;

    console.log(statesData);

    var myStyle = {
        "fillColor": "#487ba1",
        "weight": 3,
        "opacity": 1,
     "color": "#487ba1",
     "fillOpacity": 0.1
    };
    
    var statesLayer = L.geoJson(statesData,  {
        style: myStyle
      }).addTo(map);
  });
  
}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="column">
  {{> map}}
</div>
<template name="map">
  <div id='map'></div>
</template>
```

**What I get:** Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.

---

The variable "stateData" returns as a object. I just want to render the GeoJson data onto the map. I could easily do this on plain html. What is it that I don't know to properly get this working?

Comment: Why are you converting your object result.content to a String ? If the geoJSON function is looking for an Object it won't work.

Comment: Woops. That shouldn't be there. However, even when I remove .toString() it still throwing me an exception.

Comment: how is `result.content` formatted? Could it be possible that it is not automatically parsed as JSON and that it requires to be parsed with `JSON.parse(result.content)` ? Also, GeoJSON objects should have the following form: `{type: '...', coordinates: [Number, Number]}`

Comment: When I use JSON.parse(result.content), meteor crashes. I think it's because JSON.parse is trying to parse an object when JSON.parse can only accept strings in its argument. As you have seen before, I have tried adding .toString() to it and I got the same object when using JSON.parse on it. Maybe it's leaflet being buggy? But I doubt that because I copied the whole us-state.js and injected it directly into the template and it works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Your snippet is broken. It just shows `{{> map}}`, i.e., it isn't interpreting the spacebars syntax. This is probably an issue with the snippet more so than with your actual code. Can you show the actual `<body>` in your html? Alternatively, what error or unexpected behavior are you seeing?

Comment: The problem is: Leaflet won't accept a GeoJSON variable when it is one. The snippet wouldn't work out of the box because it isn't under a Meteor application.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to come from your `us-states.js` file. You want to load data from it, but instead of data you have a variable declaration in it:

```
var statesData = {
  "type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    ....
  ]
}
```

You should only keep the data in your file and remove the `var statesData =` part:

```
{
  "type":"FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    ....
  ]
}
```